# Android Studio Javascript POST from webview being changed to GET

Tags: android, post, webview

My Android Studio app is entirely a webview. The webview has some javascript (loaded from assets folder) which all works fine except ajax POSTing. All my ajax POST requests arrive at the remote web server as GET requests.

When I run the identical code (it's symlinked to the webview html and javascript, so really is identical) from my laptop, the POSTs arrive as POSTs. The webserver is on my laptop, as is Android Studio and the emulator.

Research: I've stripped the app down to nothing but a simple app that POSTs on click of an html element, but still arrives at the web server as GET.

Also searched the Internet, nothing matches this scenario, so I expect I'm doing something very stupid.

Android Studio 3.4, JRE 1.8.0.

Here's my webview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG = "MainActivity";

    WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/app.html"); //app.html loads some javascript files
    }
```

Here's the javascript in the webview:

```
$(document).on("click", "#myelement", (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://192.168.1.7/mywebserver/processdata.php',
        data: {'mydataFromForm': 'big bob'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (reply) {
            console.log('ajax success');//I see this, but that's just because processdata.php returns successfully, not because it received a POST
        }
    });
});
```

Expected: javascript ajax POST arrives at web server as POST

Actual: POST arriving as GET (per server logs)

Comment: Have your tried `myWebView.postUrl()` method?

Comment: Thanks, Ajay, but my app is javascript in the webview, not java. I might try it just to see what happens, but I'm looking for a solution to POSTing from javascript in webview.

Comment: I've just tried GET and POST from java using Volley, and both work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's the jsonp: if you specify both POST and jsonp in jquery's .ajax function, then when going to same domain, it is POSTed, and when going cross domain, it is changed to GET.

This problem is not related to Android or webview.